# White screen after login attempt

Tags: php, login, session

In my wordpress site, I built a login area. In my page-login.php I ask the user to enter his login information which after click on submit will be sent to the same page - on top of the page his entries are being checked.

My problem: After clicking on submit a white screen appears.

Here is what I have done so far:

- In my functions.php I included:

  `function register_session() {

      session_start(); 
      }

      add_action('init', 'register_session', 1);`
- In my wp-config.php I put `session_start()` onto the beginning
- In wp-includes/load.php I included `_SESSION` into the `$noUnset`-Array

Here comes the code for the login page I am talking about:

```
<?php

/* Template Name: page-login
 */
?>

<?php

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $username = $_POST['u'];
        $password = $_POST['pw'];

        $db = @new mysqli("............."); // left out for demonstration only

        $username = $db->real_escape_string($username);
        $password = $db->real_escape_string($password);

        $results = $db->query("SELECT password FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
        while ($result = $results->fetch_assoc()) {

            if (($result['passwort']) == $password) {

                session_start();

                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

                wp_redirect( 'http://www.example.de/?page_id=884' );
                exit; 

            } else {
                $error_message = 'Please check your entry.';
            }
        }

    }
?>

<?php
get_header();
?>

<form action="<?php get_permalink(); ?>" method="post">
<input type="text" name="u" autofocus>
<input type="password" name="pw">    
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Clicking on submit results in a white page. What is missing for the login process to work?

Comment: The best place to start here is to add the following two lines in your wp-config.php file:

    `error_reporting(E_ALL);`
    `ini_set( 'display_errors','1'); `

Also set WP_DEBUG to 'true' 
This is likely to help you diagnose what's going wrong.

After that, I suspect it's a Headers Already Sent issue by multiple instances of session_start.

Comment: @TomC: I just made the following changes: 1.) I removed session_start() from wp-config.php; 2.) I removed the register_session function from my functions.php. After that I tried again to log in and I got the following error message: "Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /WWWROOT/78369/htdocs/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/page-vip-lounge-login.php:7) in /WWWROOT/78369/htdocs/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/page-vip-lounge-login.php on line 30"

Comment: I solved it, I just removed unnecessary whitespace on top and unnecessary <?php / ?> tags